# How can i, send property id with stepper in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, stepper

[i want create purchase cart in list view and use stepper for change count of products and change online price but i do not know what to send product id to server.my code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynh8t.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the model using the control's binding context. Then access the corresponding ID or other properties there:

```
private void OnStepperValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Stepper stepper = sender as Stepper;
    var model = stepper.BindingContext;
    // model.id
    // model.Count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current selected value in the stepper you can just:

```
  void OnStepperValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double count = e.NewValue;
    }
```

Comment: new value of stepper has count  of product in purchase cart but i want send tow parameter count and product id.